# Trying to get a binary file

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to automate my torrent downloading, however the attempts to do it with **drakma** failed. Can anyone please help me out?

> The code goes as follows:

```
(with-open-file (file "/tmp/test.torrent"
                  :direction :output
                  :if-exists :supersede
                  :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (write-string
    (flexi-stream:octets-to-string
      (drakma:http-request "https://sukebei.nyaa.se/?page=download&tid=2265388"))
    file))
```

Comment: What does 'failed' mean? From the Stackoverflow Help: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The single drakma command is ok. However I couldn't execute your whole snippet (couldn't find flexi-stream, not in quicklisp).

Comment: @Ehvince QL package `flexi-streams` (plural)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the typo in the package name `flexi-streams` (plural), “works for me.”

However, it also returns as its primary value a sea of binary junk; personally, I'd return the filename or something.

NB. This is only useful for files small enough to fit into memory at a go; you're reading the entire remote stream, then converting it to a string, then writing it to disc.